# Silverlight Transitions effects telerik demo how-to?

Tags: c#, silverlight, transition

I would like to achieve an effect and I have no clue as to how to start.  Within [terelik's silverlight demo](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/), when you select one of the options from the menu on the left, the main section depresses and then shifts over to the left and a new section is then displayed.

I would like to do something similar. I plan on creating a small user control to display customer data.  When a user goes between records I would like to display this transition.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, the fastest way might be to create a UserControl that holds two other *'things'* such as another UserControl, a Grid, whatever. Then in this custom transition control, all you would need to do is implement the transitions (depress and shift), and manage swapping out the old item with the new one.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to do the depress and shift? Would you use a single container or multiple? I'm going to attempt and I think I will have to preload the next container in the hidden to the right, then do the depress and slide animation, then unload the hidden container to the left.